# Does the SHARED_DATABASE on Heroku support Postgresql function?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, function, postgresql, heroku

I recently back up my local Postgresql database and imported(restored) into Heroku's SHARED_DATABASE.

```
heroku pgbackups:restore SHARED_DATABASE  'url_to_pg_dump'
```

Everything seems to work except the function, which is not being created during import. I verified the nonexistence via heroku console.

I wonder if this is a limitation of heroku's SHARED_DATABASE  or  I messed some setting during   the process.

I would like to know from anyone who had experience with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Mu and Neil.

I worked with support, who pointed me to the new public beta. This looks to be next version of shared_db and I tried it and the import worked fine and postgresql function objects were restored in good order.

http://addons.heroku.com/heroku-shared-postgresql

Answer (score 3):

The current shared databases don't support user-defined functions, however, the new in-beta ones do - I have numerous triggers etc written in plpgsql running on there.

More info here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-heroku-shared-postgresql

Comment: Neil>  Thanks for your answer, which is correct, so +1. However, for benefits of others, I posted my own result from support and they have moved it from lab to public beta. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The shared databases [don't support user-defined functions](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#shared_vs_dedicated):

> In addition, the dedicated databases offer a number of advantages, including direct access (via psql or any native postgresql library), **stored procedures**, and PostgreSQL 9 support.

Emphasis mine. So they don't explicitly say that shared databases do not support stored procedures but they do note it as an extra feature of dedicated databases so the result is the same.

Comment: This is still correct for production release. see below for more updated answer on beta.